# lambda with templates

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++11

I am currently doing some exercises with templated functions. 
I had the task to write a implementation of the transform algorithm. 
I did it like the following and it works:

```
template <class in, class out, class T>
out stransform(in b, in e, out d, T p(const T&)) {
    while (b != e) 
        *d++ = p(*b++);
    return d;
}
```

As with the normal transform I have to call the predicate with an explicit type like

```
stransform(begin(vec1), end(vec1), back_inserter(vec2), predi<double>);
```

Now, I stumbled upon the C++11 Lambdas and wanted to call my function like this:

```
stransform(begin(vec1), end(vec1), back_inserter(vec2), [] (double x) ->double {return x * 10;} );
```

With that I do get a compiler error that the type cant be deduced.
This is the thing I dont understand as I am defining the T type in my lambda actually twice.

I did also check back the original transform function, with which it is working. I then checked the [implementation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/) of that one and it is obviously implemented with a template class for the whole function. 
Is that the correct way for implementing predicates with templates?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The predicate is normally a simple template argument:

```
template <class in, class out, class UnaryPredicate>
out stransform(in b, in e, out d, UnaryPredicate p);
```

This will accept pointers to function, lambdas and function objects.

Comment: I thought so after reading the implementation of transform, that makes it a lot easier, too. I still wonder why I doesn't work in the other case.

Comment: @bamboon I guess because a lambda is no function but a function object, as it may also hold state (it's a closure and not just a function).

Comment: Note that a lambda which does not perform any capturing is convertible to an ordinary function (pointer).

Comment: @spraff: but that conversion is not implemented in MSVC2010, so depending on your compiler, it may not work. (what's more, the conversion is unnecessary and potentially inefficient)

Comment: So the type of the lambda is a class which is implicitly convertible to a function pointer? Such an implicit conversion wouldn't be considered in type deduction anyway.

Comment: @visitor: The type of a lambda is an *unknown* class type that implements `operator()` for the defined parameters and returning the same return type. In the particular case of a lambda that does not capture anything (and only then) it is convertible to a function pointer with the same signature, but *only* if the lambda does not capture anything at all.

Comment: If the conversion to function pointer were implemented it still wouldn't work I think because stransform's function parameter is declared to take a T const & and the lambda does not take a double const &.

Answer (score 2):

`T p(const T&)` is the type of a function which takes a `T` *by reference*. Your lambda takes its argument by *value*.

```
stransform (
    begin (vec1),
    end (vec1),
    back_inserter (vec2),
    [] (const double & x) -> double {
        return x * 10;
    });
```

This should work. A lambda which does not perform any capturing is convertible to an ordinary function.

Comment: but why rely on an unnecessary conversion to function pointer, when you could just redefine the functor to work with functors as well as function pointers?

Comment: @jalf Redefining the functor is a better solution, I agree. If this problem arose with immutable library code then conversion can work.

Comment: @spraff: Even if the type is convertible, by using it in a template, the compiler must deduce the `T`, and at that stage I don't think that it can apply any conversions (unless the type of the lambda is a function itself, not a functor, in the case where there are no captures).

Answer (score 2):

> it is obviously implemented with a template class for the whole function

Slight aside for proper terminology: `std::transform` is a function *template*, not a function. More importantly, in a declaration of the style

```
template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class Functor>
OutputIterator
transform(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end, OutputIterator out, Functor f);
```

the template parameters `InputIterator`, `OutputIterator` and `Functor` are not required to be class types. Consider this example:

```
// function declaration
int increment(int);

int array[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
transform(std::begin(array), std::end(array), std::begin(array), increment);
```

Then `InputIterator` and `OutputIterator` are deduced to be `int*` and `Functor` is `int(*)(int)`, *none of which* is a class type -- much less a template class, but I digress. And in fact, `transform` could just as well be declared

```
template<typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator, typename Functor>
OutputIterator
transform(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end, OutputIterator out, Functor f);
```

where the keyword `typename` is a bit more clear on the nature of the template parameters: they're types, of any nature.